# How to rewrite a PostMapping request method to post a list of objects in Jhipster project

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, jhipster

I generated a project using Jhipster, and I have the generated method below that allows me to save one "productDTO", and I would like to rewrite that method to save a list of "productDTOS" for my project.
I can change the parameters to List<ProductDTOS> and add a for loop to save each productDTO, but I don't really know how to change the return part to match my requirment.

```
/**
     * {@code POST  /products} : Create a new product.
     *
     * @param productDTO the productDTO to create.
     * @return the {@link ResponseEntity} with status {@code 201 (Created)} and with body the new productDTO, or with status {@code 400 (Bad Request)} if the product has already an ID.
     * @throws URISyntaxException if the Location URI syntax is incorrect.
     */
    @PostMapping("/products")
    public ResponseEntity<ProductDTO> createProduct(@Valid @RequestBody ProductDTO productDTO) throws URISyntaxException {
        log.debug("REST request to save Product : {}", productDTO);
        if (productDTO.getId() != null) {
            throw new BadRequestAlertException("A new product cannot already have an ID", ENTITY_NAME, "idexists");
        }
        ProductDTO result = productService.save(productDTO);
        return ResponseEntity
            .created(new URI("/api/products/" + result.getId()))
            .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityCreationAlert(applicationName, false, ENTITY_NAME, result.getId().toString()))
            .body(result);
    }
```

Comment: Not really a JHipster question, it's more about Spring Boot and REST best practices. You should not use a loop, your repository has a `saveAll()`method. What you are trying to do is called a "batch or bulk operation", there are several ways to address it in a RESTful way. As you are a student, I recommend you search for "rest api bulk operations best practices" to understand pros and cons of different approaches.  Then you can update your question to address specific coding aspects.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice, I did add Jhipster tag because I did not understand the generated return part in this method, and what would be the ResponseEntity.created() and ResponseEntity.headers() in my case. I will do the search you advised me and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the method like this:

```
@PostMapping("/products")
public List<ProductDTO> createProduct(@Valid @RequestBody List<ProductDTO> productDTOs) throws URISyntaxException {

...

        List<ProductDTO> result = productService.saveAll(productDTOs);
        return result;
}
```

Of course, you need to implement the saveAll method inside the ProductService class which will be like this:

```
public List<ProductDTO> saveAll(List<ProductDTO> products) {
    return productRepository.saveAll(products);
}
```